# How to color words in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.net MVC.
Page output:

**This is Red**

**This is Blue**

**This Green**

it is not colored.I want to be colored.

I could not find the fault. Where am I doing the error?

this is my controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }
    public JsonResult RGBColor()
    {
        RGB color=new RGB();
        return Json(color,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

this is my model

```
public class RGB
{
    public string Red = "#FF0000";
    public string Green = "#00FF00";
    public string Blue = "#0000FF";
}
```

this is my view

```
@{
Layout = null;
 }
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>
 <head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
 <title>Index</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-
  3.2.1.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/RGBColor",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                $(".red").css("color", data.Red);
                $(".blue").css("color", data.Blue);
                $(".green").css("color", data.Green);
            }
        })
    })
</script>
</head>
 <body>


<div> 
    <p class="red">This is Red</p>
    <p class="blue">This is Blue</p>
    <p class="green">This is Green</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug the controller and check if you get into the `RGBColor` also it might help to add `[Httppost]` above `RGBColor`

Comment: You forgot to include `[HttpPost]` over `public JsonResult RGBColor()`. If the method not found, the CSS assignment never executed.

Comment: ı added [HttpPost] but not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the src attribute in a script tag, the content of the script tag will be ignored, thus your javascript code is never executed. You need to do:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
```